# Redirect any request to a file on server to another file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm not good at htaccess, What I'm trying is to redirect any `/oldFile.php` to `/newFile.php` which should include redirecting  any `/oldFile.php?somequery&anotherquery` to `/newFile.php?somequery&anotherquery`

I've checked many answers here, but I can't find anyone fits my needs

Your help is greatly appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what is already in your `.htaccess` file, this is just a standard redirect:

```
Redirect 302 /oldFile.php /newFile.php
```

The query string from the request is copied to the target URL by default - there is nothing special you need to do here in that respect.

Note that this is currently a 302 - temporary - redirect (the `302` is optional in the above directive). If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301 only once you have confirmed that it works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite I've tryied Redirect 301 before which solve some of issues, now I tried Redirect 302 and still same, some issues can't be solved, what do you suggest ?

Comment: `Redirect 301` and `Redirect 302` are the same - just a different status code. What do you mean "some issues can't be solved"? The above performs the redirect as stated in the question. Do you have other directives in `.htaccess`? Maybe you have a conflict? Note that if you have existing mod_rewrite directives then you probably should use mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead to avoid potential conflicts. But otherwise, using the `Redirect` directive, as stated in my answer, is the correct/recommended way to do this. Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: I mean looks that I have other issue need to be fixed, I'll check the htaccess it may has other rule override the redirect